# ¿Cómo obtener varias columnas con la opción de write?

Tags: python

Queridos amigos de Stack Over Flow, necesito su ayuda.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd


acciones = [0,1,2]

for i in acciones:

    lista = [0,1,2,3,4]

    df=pd.DataFrame(lista)

    print(df)
```

Y me da el siguiente resultado:

```
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

¿Cómo hago para obtener el siguiente resultado?

```
   0           0           0
0  0        0  0        0  0 
1  1        1  1        1  1
2  2        2  2        2  2
3  3        3  3        3  3
4  4        4  4        4  4
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es lo mismo....

Comment: @Christian deseo que las columnas se impriman una al lado de la otra

Comment: `print(df, end='\t')`

Comment: @Christian gracias pero el código no me da lo que deseo

Comment: Lo siento, he estado alejado de python últimamente. La respuesta que te dan es acertada y deberías hecharle un ojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil sería utilizar los métodos para aplicar estilos en pandas ([documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)), aplicando `set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")` a cada `dataframe`, pero debes utilizar `display_html` del módulo `IPython`

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display_html

acciones = [0,1,2]
output = ''

for i in acciones:
    lista = [0,1,2,3,4]
    df=pd.DataFrame(lista)
    output += df.style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'").set_caption('df ' + str(i))._repr_html_()

display_html(output, raw=True)
```

Esto devuelve:

[image: Dataframe lado a lado]

Si lo quisieras hacer con `print` entonces tendrías que primero imprimir las columnas y luego iterar por las filas de cada `dataframe`

Comment: No me corre ese código ya instale ipython y jinja2

Comment: Y ¿Qué error aparece? Así sin información esta difícil